# Type '{ variableName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am getting this error to me and reading makes complete sense, but it makes no sense to me as to why I am getting it.

In the example below `myOtherVariable` is a string and `variableName` or so I thought... Am I missing something here?

```
Type '{ variableName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Here is how it is being called

```
const DynamicArea = (variableName: string) => (
   <div>Eventually this will be filled with some cool data</div>
);


export const myFunction = () => {
   const myOtherVariable = '';

   return (
       <DynamicArea variableName={myOtherVariable} />
   );
};
```

Comment: add the typescript tag to your question

Comment: That's not how react props work: `DynamicArea` gets constructed with one argument, and it's an object with all the properties you used in your JSX. So at the very least you need `const DynamicArea = ({ variableName: string }) => ...`.

Comment: your code does not define a type but reassigns the destructured ``variableName`` into a variable called ``string`` @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this by destructuring your props. Thats a common pitfall because you are typing the props object as a string but the props parameter is an object and you want to destructure a certain property out of it instead in your code:

```
const DynamicArea = ({ variableName }: { variableName: string }) => (
    <div>Eventually this will be filled with some cool data</div>
);
```

As you see maybe now the error `Type '{ variableName: string; }' is not assignable to type 'string'` is indicating it that you are passing the component a `{ variableName: string }` type but you declared it as `string`

Answer (score 1):

The code bit `(variableName: string)` means nothing in Javascript.

You are mixing up with typescript, where it means that your "variableName" is a string type.

To fix it, in javascript you just re-write your component to be:

```js
const DynamicArea = (variableName) => (
   <div>Eventually this will be filled with some cool data</div>
);
```

There is no need to indicate what type your variable is in javascript.

Comment: I get this error when doing that. I tried that previously too `Parameter 'variableName' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7006)`. I can add `any` to it instead and string and it works, but thats isn't a good solution

Comment: Can you try to call the prop in a random place inside your component like `<div>{variableName}</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Ilja KO mentioned the simpler version and probably better for this scenario, but I want to add an alternative to the correct answer from Ilja.

For TypeScript understand the prop types for the component, you can define its prop types explicitly as interface:

```
interface DynamicAreaProps {
  variableName: string;
}

const DynamicArea: React.FC<DynamicAreaProps> = ({ variableName }) => (
  <div>Eventually this will be filled with some cool data</div>
);

export const myFunction = () => {
  const myOtherVariable = '';

  return (
    <DynamicArea variableName={myOtherVariable} />
  );
};
```